# getRootInActiveWindow() giving null value

Tags: android, accessibility, android-service, android-view, android-windowmanager

```
 private void click() {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Click [%d, %d]", cursorLayout.x, cursorLayout.y));
- AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = getRootInActiveWindow();
        if (nodeInfo == null) return;
        AccessibilityNodeInfo nearestNodeToMouse = findSmallestNodeAtPoint(nodeInfo, cursorLayout.x, cursorLayout.y + 50);
        if (nearestNodeToMouse != null) {
            logNodeHierachy(nearestNodeToMouse, 0);
            nearestNodeToMouse.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
        }
        nodeInfo.recycle();
    }
```

I am using  AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = getRootInActiveWindow(); i am getting null value here

I try

```
view.createAccessibilityNodeInfo();
```

By these method i got node. but I got one error  seald unreachable like that.

```
view.getRootView().createAccessibilityNodeInfo();
```

[xml file for accesibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vR57.jpg)

[ManifestFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fldv.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your [accessibility service config](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#service-config) file contents?

Comment: yes where to send

Comment: You can modify this question, or put a link to a git repository :)

Comment: i attached accessibility xml and service menifiest file screen shot

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I can't seem to get you to show the contents of your service config... I don't want to confuse you with mine, but I feel this example may be more productive.

In your manifest, you'll need to have an `accessibility_service_config` file referenced. The name is not important.

```
<service
    android:name="..."
    android:enabled="true"
    android:label="..."
    android:description="..."
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
</service>
```

Then `res/xml/accessibility_service_config.xml` needs to be something along the lines of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagReportViewIds"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:canPerformGestures="false"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="..."
    />
```

It could be that you just need to set `canRetrieveWindowContent` to true. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo#attr_android:canRetrieveWindowContent):

> Attribute whether the accessibility service wants to be able to retrieve the active window content. This setting cannot be changed at runtime.
>
> Required to allow setting the [#AccessibilityServiceInfo#FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/package-summary) flag.
>
> May be a boolean value, such as "true" or "false".

Or it could be the contents of  needs at least `android:accessibilityFlags="flagReportViewIds"`

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo#FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS):

> This flag requests that the [AccessibilityNodeInfos](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo) obtained by an [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) contain the id of the source view. The source view id will be a fully qualified resource name of the form "package:id/name", for example "foo.bar:id/my_list", and it is useful for UI test automation. This flag is not set by default.

I strongly recommend you configure your service properly - I don't recommend copying and pasting my service config verbatim.

Comment: I try my best to get window content but still I am not getting. I am sharing my github https://github.com/mkumar7404508129/accesibility please check it tell me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your service config XML is malformed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <-- the angle bracket shouldn't be here -->
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="200"
    android:packageNames="com.example.accesibility"
    android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"
</accessibility-service>
```

change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="200"
    android:packageNames="com.example.accesibility"
    android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"> <-- the angle bracket should be here -->
</accessibility-service>
```