# Why AccessibilityWindowInfo.root return null?

Tags: android, accessibility

The Android Accessibility Service can obtain the root View in two ways:

1. `window.root`
2. `rootInActiveWindow`
   The window I get active by the first way is often a null value, and there are no child nodes. In the same interface, `rootInActiveWindow` successfully obtained the window.

Why does this happen? There should be no difference between the windows I get in any two ways?

The `window` obtained by `rootInActiveWindow` is sometimes null, how should I ensure that I get the `window`.

`config`

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:packageNames="com.example.accesibility"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds|flagRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    />
```

Comment: Without a code example it's difficult to assess what is wrong. Have you seen the answers over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74717163/getrootinactivewindow-giving-null-value/74921885#74921885 ? Pay particular attention to the service config XML

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon Before asking the question, I have retrieved all the possibilities of set config. Now I have attached the xml code. I don't think it is a problem of setting. I have already set everything that can be set.